# Center aligning nav bar with @media query not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm creating a video hub with an navigation bar. Instead of using an accordion nav collapse I simply want the menu to carry onto the next line and be centered. This is the code I used to have that effect.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px){
  .navbar ul li {
    float: center;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .last {
    background: none !important; 
  }

}
```

This snippet works perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox and IE the nav bar does not center. The media query change for the .last class works so I know the issue isn't with the media query but with how Firefox and IE render the nav bar.

Does anyone have advice on how to fix this? I can share more code if need be. Here is the site: http://fivebehaviors.hubs.vidyard.com/

Comment: Float doesn't allow "center". You can try `text-align:center` on the `ul`

Comment: This does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

As sdleihssirhc said, I would think `text-align:center;` would work on the ul. It may not be working because it seems that the ul width extends beyond the content, so perhaps try putting `width:auto;` on the ul. On the other hand, you could do the same for the ul and for the navbar div and try putting `margin:0 auto;` to get it centered.